# React - Sending uploaded images as url to an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending multiple images to an API but the way I do it sends it as an object but I need to send it as a URL.

**State:**

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
```

**Image uploader:**

```
 const fileSelectHandler = (e) => {
        setFiles([...files, ...e.target.files]);
      };

<input
  type="file"
  className="form-control"
  id="customFile"
  multiple
  onChange={fileSelectHandler}
/>
```

**Expected sending package:**

```
"pic": [
            {
                "url": "760634d2-f8ec-4caa-9a2d-14a8828cfb5dpetplace.jpg"
            },
            {
                "url": "760634d2-f8ec-4caa-9a2d-14a8828cfb5dpetplace.jpg"
            }
       ]
```

Comment: how does it look like now? the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState([]);

   const fileSelectHandler = (e) => {
   const [file] = e.target.files;
   setFiles([...files, { url: file.name }]);
  };

  const picObj = { pic: files };
  console.log(picObj);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        className="form-control"
        id="customFile"
        multiple
        onChange={fileSelectHandler}
      />
 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here alink to the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pine-2k8t9?file=/src/App.js:0-625

Comment: Why are we using two input fields?

Comment: Also, this code is giving this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: @HusnainMehmood - correct, no need for 2 inputs. It was for quick testing purposes :) . concerning the undefined, when do you get that ? its seems to work fine .

Comment: Yes sorry, it gave an unexpected error. Working fine now! Thanks! :)